# How to add file extension to the files which do not have an extension in a specific folder using Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have folder (say `c:\folder`) in which many files reside. All of them are HTML documents. But some of them have not `.html` extension. I want to add them `.html` file extension using command prompt at once.

All the files which have not extension end with `^` character. All the file names have different lengths.

I have tried

```
ren *^ *^.html
```

but it did not rename all the files and prompted that

> There is already an existing file with same name or file could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is an escape character in cmd.exe.  You have to escape it.  Try `ren *^^ *^^.html`.

Answer (score 11):

I try this and it works :

```
  C:\test>ren *. *.html
```

[image]

---

**Update :**
with ^ in the name :

[image]

Comment: Thanks but not all the files to be changed. Just the files which have no extension

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ Just the files that haven't extension will change.Others will remain unchanged.

Comment: for example I tried with **"a^"** and **"b.html"** in **"test"** folder. And after, I have **a^.html** and **b.html** inside.

Comment: @user3580433 you can't see the rename for b.html because it was earlier b.html itself :\ in other words, it is renamed but because prior to rename the filename & extension was same you think it's not changed

Comment: @Sathya :Yes!I know! but what's the difference? the out put is what we want :/ you are nervous for the calculating load that CPU should handle?!!! come on dude! :)

Comment: eh, it's not about the load. there's a third file called c.jpg & you'll rename that to c.html which isn't what @ÖzkanÖZLÜ wants

Comment: @Sathya  yes,but as mentioned in question "All of the reside files are HTML documents." and he want to add `.html` to some of them.

Comment: @Sathya you was right. I checked it and change it(first `*` changed to `*.`). check the update plz. thanks.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ give us a response pleade! Is your problem solved?

Comment: didn't work. Maybe it it useful for alpha-numeric file names. Since my files have ^ character, this suggestion not helped me

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ check update section in question . I add a new photo! my file also have ^ in its name. what kind of error do you receive?

Comment: I have got '**The syntax of the command is incorrect**' when I apply the following command: `ren *. *.html`

Comment: That is really weird!!!! use copy& past plz. (copy this line and paste in command-line) : `ren *. *.html`

Answer (score 3):

The following works (you may wish first to add **echo** before the **ren** to make sure that the command is doing what you want):

```
for %f in (*.) do ren "%f" "%f.html"
```

You need the quotes in case the file name has embedded blanks.

Comment: this did not work. neither an error did not occur, nor a change

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Make sure that you can see the files you want to rename when you type `for %f in (*.) do echo %f`. If not, post a `dir` listing and I'll recreate the same file names and see what happens.